# About matlab directory

Tags: matlab, directory

My different set of data are stored in different folders in same directory. Then I used cd command to get path of each set of data. I wrote function (Max_get.m) file which use both set of images. Now what I want to ask is whether Max_get.m file can run by loading these images **from different directory** or all images (these 2 set of images) must be in same folder?

Thanks you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have given full path of image file, then it can run even these are in different folders

if you not specified full path then these are must be in working directory.

Comment: I have just give the path at the begining of Max_get.m file like this; emt=imread('D:\Matlab\emt_opp') and vgt=imread('D:\Matlab\vgt_opp'). Is it ok?